# Beta Binomial Distirbution - Updating beta with 0 occurence

Tags: bayesian, zero-inflation, beta-binomial-distribution

I am dealing with different problem where a count data has to be modelled either with binomial distribution or hypergeometric. I have done a extensive literature read and it seems that occurence equal to 0 (count equal to 0) does not provide any information to te posterior distribution of a potential beta distribution for the probability of occurrence. I would like to know:

- Which is the mathematical justification for this?
- In case of having a real proportion dsitribution close to 0, why count=0 would not bring any information to the posterior. I consider it does provide information since in this case, 0 is plausible and likely value

Regards

Juan

Comment: Starting with a beta prior $\theta \sim \text{Beta}(\alpha, \beta)$, a binomial likelihood, and the observation of $k$ successes and $n-k$ failures in $n$ trials yields the posterior distribution
$$
\theta \sim \text{Beta}(\alpha+k, \beta+n-k).
$$ If you conduct 0 trials, then this posterior is $$
\theta \sim \text{Beta}(\alpha+0, \beta+0),
$$
which is no different than the prior. Immediately, the posterior predictive distribution of a beta-binomial model is beta-binomial with parameters $\alpha + 0, \beta+0$.

Comment: Hi, I may have not explained well. My situation is that more than observation is n=600 (e.g) and k=0 (no success). This should update my alpha to alpha+0 and beta is beta+n right?

Comment: $\beta + 600 - 0 = \beta + 600$ and $\alpha +0 = \alpha$.

Comment: So, when using a bayesian approach to compute the posterior distribution of α and β, these observations with 0 counts are used to update them right? Why did I read several post where they say zero count must either treated different or using some transformation technique such a laplace smoothing?

Comment: I can't comment on a paper I haven't read. If you're asking about some specific procedure, you'll need to [edit] to ask about it, include a complete citation, and reproduce the part that you're confused about.

Comment: Some frequentist methods perform poorly unless there is at least one success and at least one failure: for example a Wald confidence interval on your $(0,600)$ data would give $[0,0]$. One frequentist approach in this situation is to use the [rule of three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(statistics)) which in your example would suggest a confidence interval of $[0,\frac1{200}]$.

Comment: Bayesian methods using a Beta conjugate prior do what @Sycorax suggests, updating to $\text{Beta}(\alpha, \beta+600)$ posterior. If the prior is say a Haldane improper prior with $\alpha=0, \beta=0$ then this too can give unsatisfactory results unless there is at least one success and at least one failure: this may be why many Bayesians start with a Jeffreys' prior with $\alpha=\frac12, \beta=\frac12$ or a uniform prior $\alpha=1, \beta=1$.